# Partial differentiation using Coqelicot on Coq

Tags: coq, differentiation

I want to partially differentiate functions which expects n arguments for arbitrary natural number n. I hope to differentiate arbitrary an argument only once and not the others.

```
Require Import Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.

Definition myFunc (x y z:R) :R:=
 x^2 + y^3 + z^4.
```

I expect function `3*(y^2)` when I differentiate `myFunc` with y.

I know [partial_derive](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Derive_2d.html#f) in [Coquelicot](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Coquelicot.html).

```
Definition partial_derive (m k : nat) (f : R → R → R) : R → R → R :=
  fun x y ⇒ Derive_n (fun t ⇒ Derive_n (fun z ⇒ f t z) k y) m x.
```

`partial_derive` can partially differentiate `f:R → R → R`, but not possible for arbitrary number of arguments.

I thought about using dependent type listR.

```
Inductive listR :nat -> Type:=
|RO : Euc 0
|Rn : forall {n}, R -> listR n -> listR (S n).

Notation "[ ]" := RO.
Notation "[ r1 , .. , r2 ]" := (Rn r1 .. ( Rn r2 RO ) .. ).
Infix ":::" := Rn (at level 60, right associativity).

Fixpoint partial_derive_nth {n} (k:nat) (f : listR n -> R) (e:listR n): listR n -> R:=
```

`k` specifies argument number to differentiate.
We can not define partial_derive_nth like partial_derive because we can not specify the name of arguments of `fun` in recursion.

Please tell me how to partially differentiate functions which has arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your function `myFunc`, you can write the partial derivative like so:

```
Definition pdiv2_myFunc (x y z : R) :=
 Derive (fun y => myFunc x y z) y.
```

You can then prove that it has the value you expect for any choice of `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Most of the proof can be done automatically, thanks to the tactics provided in `Coquelicot`.

```
Lemma pdiv2_myFunc_value (x y z : R) :
   pdiv2_myFunc x y z = 3 * y ^ 2.
Proof.
unfold pdiv2_myFunc, myFunc.  
apply is_derive_unique.
auto_derive; auto; ring.
Qed.
```

I am a bit surprised that the automatic tactic `auto_derive` does not handle a goal of the form `Derive _ _ = _`, so I have to apply theorem `is_derive_unique` myself.